# how to get elements by a tag name in Saxparser in android

Tags: android, saxparser

in my app when i click a button it gets an xml file from an url and it moves to a new actvity B. In activity B i have a list view, where the tag "name" are been listed out.

My xml file is as follows

```
  <search>
         <data>
          <userid>1</userid>
              <name>Jean</name>
              <address>dbvsvksn</address>
              <dob>Mar 3</dob>
          <country>us</country>
         </data>
         <data>
          <userid>2</userid>
              <name>Anne</name>
              <address>dbvsvksn ,</address>
              <dob>Jun 2<dob>
          <country>us</country>
         </data>
         <data>
          <userid>3</userid>
              <name>J</name>
              <address>dbvsvksn ,</address>
              <dob>Dec 6<dob>
          <country>us</country>
         </data>
    </search>
```

when i click on any item on the list view it opens a new Activity C. Here in a text view i want to display the name i have clicked in the previous activity and i have to show the address, dob, country of the name that been clicked.

Now i have listed out the name's using Sax parser in activity B and using intent i have printed the name in activity C but how to get the other related tag's.

please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make a class `Users` containing fields like id, name, address, dob etc with their `setter getter` method. and when you receive XML, parse it using `DOM`, and save their values in array of `Users` Object. By this you can access every field by just calling getter methods. You can pass that objects to other activity, or access them anywhere if they are static.

Comment: The idea is correct, under the assumption that during Activity B, he can passes that through to Activity C either via setting the data via the Intent or a SharedPreference.  Activty C only has to parse the incoming data and display.

Comment: So what you have done till now..? made a class Users..? parsed it..? where you got the problem?